# Spring LDAP Authentication using uniqueMember Attribute

Tags: spring-boot, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

While I was trying to authenticate with ***uid={0},ou=Groups*** I could succesfully login but couldn't when I tried to shrink pattern to a specific group.
***uid={0},CN=ROM,OU=USER,OU=APPOU,ou=Groups***

I probably need to use uniqueMember attribute but couldn't find a way. How can I authenticate user with a groups's uniqueMember attribute by just using his/her uid?

[image: LDAP Group]

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .ldapAuthentication()
        .contextSource()
            .url("ldapUrl")
                .managerDn("username")
                .managerPassword("password")
            .and()
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},CN=ROM,OU=USER,OU=APPOU,ou=Groups");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way for who is interested in:

```
 public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
    .ldapAuthentication()
    .contextSource()
        .url(ldapUrl")
            .managerDn("username")
            .managerPassword("password")
        .and()
            .userSearchFilter("uid={0}")
            .groupSearchBase("CN=ROM,OU=USER,ou=APPOU,ou=Groups")
            .groupSearchFilter("uniqueMember{0}");
```

}